# Put text in "TOP BAR" 2 lines + image

Tags: android

I'm trying put text in to bar, I only put (buttons), I don't know if I can put text 2 lines + image.

Here are references as changing the color:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

in this other picture is displayed, as you can put more text in the top bar

http://www.whatsapp.com/img/v3/es/s1-chat.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create your own view and set it for your `ActionBar`: [setCustomView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setCustomView%28int%29).

You cannot achieve what you want with the standard layout. For plenty of examples [look here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    // add the custom view to the action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar_view);
    EditText search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
    search.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
          KeyEvent event) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Search triggered",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return false;
      }
    });
    actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM
        | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME);
  }

}
```

Source: [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews)

Comment: looks interesting, Can you put any example ?

Comment: I put a tutorial link in the post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it.
I'd advise you just to create a layout that would act like a top bar in your application.
This way you would be able to put there anything you want.

If you have more than one activity that needs to have this top bar, then use fragments instead of activities (to avoid your custom top bar from being animated when new activities are being opened).